# How to make private Facebook "likes" on a page?

Tags: facebook, privacy

In constant urge to keep myself updated on what's going on in other universities, I would like to *like* the official Facebook pages of these universities; but I also want to keep this activity private and not want to share it on my wall as to which universities I have recently liked.

Currently, I like the university and then goto my wall and remove the wall post, isn't there a privacy customization for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Hit this link path:

   > Account > Privacy Settings > Connecting on Facebook - View Settings

   It'll take you to a page entitled, "Choose Your Privacy Settings > Connecting on Facebook"
2. Scroll down to the last section, "See your likes, activities and other connections"
3. Set the privacy on that to **Only Me**.

Now, when you like a university (or anything else) it shouldn't show up on your wall.

Comment: I already had that set to Only Me. I still see the notifications on my Wall; but how do I make sure only I see it?

Comment: Ask a friend or create another profile and see if it displays. @vai

Comment: This answer is old (no loner applies) as of 03/2012

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/25134/490 for the new way to do it.