# How to set default visibility of FB likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

For some reason when I like something on some webpage and click "post to Facebook", this is posted to my profile with a lock icon, meaning that only I can see it. I then need to manually go to Facebook, find this like on my profile page and share it.

Where can I set the default visibility of Facebook likes so that my likes are shared immediately, without the need to go to facebook.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The privacy of pages you Like is set on your timeline or profile.  If you have timeline, go to your timeline and click on Likes, and then Edit in the upper right corner (Edit does not show up until you hover over it):

[image: Timeline - Edit Likes]

Then you can set the privacy of each category of Likes using the button to its right.  Most of them are in the category "Other Pages You Like":

[image: Timeline - Other Pages You Like]

If you still have the old profile, go to your profile by clicking your name at the top, then click Edit Profile, then the appropriate category that you want to change in the left sidebar.  "Other Pages you Like" can be found on the "Activities and Interests" tab.  Change the privacy setting using the button to its right:

[image: Profile - Other Pages You Like]

Answer (score 1):

The privacy of Like's is dependent on the default setting on your [privacy settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy) page. Change it to something that isn't locked.

I tested this and verified it's this setting by liking a page somewhere else. In order to see the change take effect you'll need to clear your cache and reload the page (otherwise your old settings will be used to post the `like` to your wall/timeline)

Comment: It is actually not locked in my case, it's set to "Friends" (that big icon in the "Control Your Default Privacy" section). Still, likes are posted as private by default.